# How to Speed Up Slow CMake Cache Generations?

Tags: cmake, toolchain

Generating CMake cache in a big project can take multiple minutes, and it's such a chore if you've only done a minor change and need to regenerate it.

1. Is there any tool or method to benchmark what CMake is spending its time doing when generating its cache? Like
2. Though there are some tricks which are well known to speed up compiletime, I've heard of few if any ways of reducing cache generation time. Are there any such usual suspects to look for when trying to speed it up?

Comment: What CMake cache you are talking about? If you talk about `CMakeCache.txt` file which contains information about CMake cache variables, then every time the project is reconfigured that file is read at the beginning and is written at the end of configuration.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Am I misunderstanding what CMake needs to generate? Specifically I am thinking of if I added a "add_subdirectory", or just in general made a change to any of the CMakeLists.txt file, I would have to regenerate the cache, right? Visual Studio refers to this as "Generate Cache" at least. Is this actually part of the build solution or something else?

Comment: Hm, [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/open-existing-cmake-caches-in-visual-studio/) they actually refer to `CMakeCache.txt` as a "CMake Cache" and try to reduce its generation. From my understanding of CMake, the file `CMakeCache.txt` is created relatively fast. Much longer process is generating the Visual Studio project (solution?) upon the end of parsing of `CMakeLists.txt`. And `CMakeCache.txt` cannot reduce generation of Visual Studio project. But I could be wrong..

Comment: CMake uses 2 phases to configure a project: One to parse the `CMakeLists.txt` files, generate a internal data structure holding the info about targets ect. and one phase where it writes the build system to the binary dir. From my usual experience I'd assume the first phase is where most of the time is spent. Writing the `CMakeLists.txt` files well and limiting things like `execute_process`, `configure_file`, ect.. Don't make any assumptions though: You can use `cmake-gui` to trigger both steps seperately which should allow you to tell, if generation or configuration takes most of the time.